# Reverse Proxy - Using Subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I cant use cname, therefore i would like to split my services into subdirectorys.

```
location /ha/  
    {
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:58123/;   #local IP of my HA server
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection       "upgrade";
        }
```

When i do this i get the HA Logo, but in the developer console i see that he tries to load files from the main side.

e.g. instead `/ha/frontend_latest/app.83207343.js` i get `/frontend_latest/app.83207343.js`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because your `/ha/` page lists `/frontend_latest/app.83207343.js` as a resource. You have three ways to solve this:

1. Tell your application that it should use relative paths, e.g. `frontend_latest/app.83207343.js`
2. Tell your application that it should use absolute, but correct paths, e.g. `/ha/frontend_latest/app.83207343.js`.
3. Use something like [ngx_http_sub](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) to do a rewrite on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but looks like HomeAssistant is stubborn and will never add this
https://github.com/home-assistant/architecture/issues/156#issuecomment-478183627
Therefore 1 and 2 isn't working.
I tried variant 3 a little bit, but it looks like then I never can run something on / ?

Comment: Go with subdomains.